# Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 on another drive than C:

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I install the Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 on **another** drive than C: (like D:).

Actually, when I install it from the windows store, it is stored at :

```
C:\Users\[$USER]\AppData\Local\Packages
```

Comment: Directory junctions will work, as long as you can protect the target directory.

Comment: This is not officially supported at the moment, though there are some hacky workarounds : https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/449

Comment: You could try to change the base path in the registry and move the files manually. Go to [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss] and search for BasePath.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/crazy-max/7d8eee9e35a6706cda77a179bd2f69ad). You will need to install LxRunOffline first.

Note that this will also enable transferring of existing Linux distributions and installation of all kind of distributions.

Comment: I encountered a 404 in the tutorial, but I believe a similar solution can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/crazy-max/7d8eee9e35a6706cda77a179bd2f69ad).

Comment: @Leonardo I have edited the answer to your link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The WSL2 remains on drive C, but it is possible to move the distribution (Ubuntu) to another drive (D) and save C space.

Credits for the original answer: https://superuser.com/a/1618643/1771934

---

**Move Ubuntu Installation to Drive D:**

1. **Export Ubuntu:**

   - Create a backup folder on drive D:

     ```bash
     mkdir D:\backup
     ```
   - Export the Ubuntu distribution to a tar file in the backup folder:

     ```bash
     wsl --export Ubuntu D:\backup\ubuntu.tar
     ```
2. **Unregister the Existing Distribution:**

   - Remove the existing Ubuntu distribution from drive C:

     ```bash
     wsl --unregister Ubuntu
     ```
3. **Import Ubuntu to Drive D:**

   - Create a new folder on drive D for the WSL installation:

     ```bash
     mkdir D:\wsl
     ```
   - Import the Ubuntu distribution from the backup tar file to the new folder on drive D:

     ```bash
     wsl --import Ubuntu D:\wsl\ D:\backup\ubuntu.tar
     ```
4. **Set Default User:**

   - By default, Ubuntu may utilize the root user. To revert to the previous user, follow these steps:

     - Open the Ubuntu App Folder. You can do this by running the following command:

       ```bash
       cd %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
       ```
     - Set the default user by running the following command and replacing `<username>` with your desired username:

       ```bash
       ubuntu config --default-user <username>
       ```

Now, your Ubuntu installation is moved to drive D, and the default user is set to the specified username.

*Note: Ensure that you replace `<username>` with your actual username.*

Comment: If we import as `Ubuntu2`. we could have two instances of ubuntu distro running at the same time, if we want. Then `ubuntu config --default-user` sets the default user for which instance, or both ?

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?